# Test runner (jest) failing to import expo modules

Tags: react-native, jestjs, expo

I'm writing some component tests for a React Native app. I'm using `expo`'s `BarCodeScanner` for one of my components. In my `jest` test, I have a line that says `import { BarCodeScanner } from 'expo';`. This line alone (without anything that uses it further down in my test code) causes the following error:

> The Expo SDK requires Expo to run. It appears the native Expo modules
>   are unavailable and this code is not running on Expo. Visit
>   https://docs.expo.io to learn more about developing an Expo project.

Anybody have any idea on how I can import the `BarCodeScanner` to my test file?

Comment: Clearly there isn't a full on expo app running when the tests are run, and I'm assuming this is where the problem lies. I'm hopeful there's a way to get around that though!

Comment: Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve at https://snack.expo.io/ or a Github repo?

Comment: @riwu - the above example is an MCVE. If you have a file that simply has that import statement, then run it with the `jest` command, you'll end up with this error message. perhaps you'll need to add an `it('dummy test', () => { expect(1).toBe(1) });` line after in case jest requires an actual test to run a file.

Answer (score 5):

I did a bit of digging and it appears that this is a common problem with Expo and Jest. There are a couple of issues open currently related to Jest Tests:

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+jest

One solution here sparked my interest:

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1705

It appears if you create your own Jest setup file and "require()" the expo component in there and downgrade expo and expo-jest to v26 it works. Example from the link above:

package.json:

```
...
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./setupJest"
},
...
```

setupJest.js:

```
require('stacktrace-parser');
```

Hope this helps you some bit. Let me know how you get on or if you have any queries and i will dig a bit more if possible :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out next week when I'm back onto React Native development, and will update here. I'll give you the bounty because you're the only person to respond thus far and this answer seems promising!

Comment: I got same error when updated `expo` + expo RN version to 30.0 but forgot to bump `jest-expo` package. All works fine when all three have same version.